# How to create Regional Health checks with Google Deployment Manager

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-deployment-manager

I am trying to create a `regionBackendService` using `Google Deployment Manager`.
The problem is I can't find a way to create a `regional health check` that the `regionBackendService` accepts.

This is my latest attempt:

```
  - name: "api-healthcheck"
    type: compute.v1.healthCheck
    properties:
      name: "api-healthcheck"
      region: europe-west3
      type: "HTTP"
      httpHealthCheck:
        port: 8089
        requestPath: '/healthz'
  - name: "api-backend-service"
    type: "compute.v1.regionBackendService"
    metadata:
      dependsOn:
        - api-healthcheck
    properties:
      name: "api-backend-service"
      region: europe-west3
      backends:
        - group: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/...(points to a instance group)
      health checks:
        - $(ref.api-healthcheck.selfLink)
      protocol: TCP
      loadBalancingScheme: EXTERNAL
```

Unluckily but expectedly, this leads to the following error:

```
NetLB supports regional health checks only
```

In fact, I should be creating a `compute.v1.RegionalHealthCheck` as clearly stated in [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-check-concepts#lb_guide).

Unluckily, `Deployment Manager` [doesn't seem to support such object](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/supported-resource-types).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that, despite it not being listed within supported types, it is possible to create a regional health check by using the `compute.v1.regionHealthChecks` (yes, plural) type.

```
- name: "api-healthcheck"
    type: compute.v1.regionHealthChecks
    properties:
      name: "api-healthcheck"
      region: europe-west3
      type: "HTTP"
      httpHealthCheck:
        port: 8089
        requestPath: '/healthz'
```

So it looks like a problem in the documentation or me not finding it.